# Incrementar valor de varios Inputs con botones más y menos en HTML con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy desarrollando un pequeño ejemplo de una clase, donde los alumnos tienen un sistema de puntaje y este se puede incrementar a través de botones + o -, pero me surge el problema que al darle un cierto puntaje a uno y luego a otro, el segundo toma los puntos del primero y se van acumulando, así y así para otro alumno. Este es mi código HTML y el script:

```js
var i = 1;
var b = [ {id:0, alumno: "Alonso", puntos: 0}, {id:1, alumno: "Sebas", puntos: 0}, {id:2, alumno: "Juan", puntos: 0} ];

document.getElementById('btnVerAlumnos').addEventListener ('click', function() {
    var text= "";
    long = b.length;
    if(long) {
        for (var c=0;c<long;c++) {
            text+= `<li class="card">
            ${b[c].alumno}
            <button onclick="contadormenos(${c})">-</button>
            <input id="${c}" type="text" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;" value="${i}">
            <button onclick="contadormas(${c})">+</button>
            </li>`
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('lista_alumnos_conectados').innerHTML = text;
});

function contadormas(index) {
    i = i + 1;
    var cant = document.getElementById(`${index}`);
    cant.value = i;
    if(cant.value == 1){
        i=1;
        cant.value=1;
    }
}

function contadormenos(index) {
    if (i >= 2) {
        i = i - 1;
        var cant = document.getElementById(`${index}`);
        cant.value = i;
        if (cant.value == 1) {
            i=1;
            cant.value=1;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<a id="btnVerAlumnos">Lista de alumnos</a>
<ul id="lista_alumnos_conectados"></ul>
```

Si alguien tiene una mejor idea o que es lo que pasa me ayudaría mucho. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que noto, `i` es una variable global, por lo tanto cada vez que hagas la comparación estos se irán acumulando en 1 sola variable, por eso cada vez que sumas agregas la cantidad total de votos en 1 solo alumno. Para solucionar tu problema deberías declarar un contador aparte en cada uno de las funciones `contadormas` y `contadormenos`.

Me cuentas como te va.

Comment: Hola, si estuve analizándolo luego y me percaté de eso, más bien lo que hice fue eliminar la variable `i` y reemplazarlas todas por el atributo de los objetos llamado puntos como `b[indice].puntos` donde el indice es el parámetro de las funciones contadormas y contadormenos. Ahora estoy tratando de poder mantener dichos valores porque al colocarlos en un modal, vuelven a cero.

Answer (score 1):

Tus funciones de `contadormenos` y `contadormas` están calculando sobre una variable compartida (`i`). Pero en su lugar, cada vez que se presione el botón querrás ver qué valor hay y añadir o quitar uno a ese valor. Tus funciones `contadormas` y `contadormenos` podrían ser así:

```
function contadormas (index) {
    document.getElementById(`${index}`).value++;
}

function contadormenos (index) {
    var cant = document.getElementById(`${index}`).value--;
}
```

Luego puedes añadirle la lógica que quieras, por ejemplo para que no bajen de 0 los números. Así quedaría:

```js
var i = 1;
var b = [ {id:0, alumno: "Alonso", puntos: 0}, {id:1, alumno: "Sebas", puntos: 0}, {id:2, alumno: "Juan", puntos: 0} ];

document.getElementById('btnVerAlumnos').addEventListener ('click', function() {
    var text= "";
    long = b.length;
    if(long) {
        for (var c=0;c<long;c++) {
            text+= `<li class="card">
            ${b[c].alumno}
            <button onclick="contadormenos(${c})">-</button>
            <input id="${c}" type="text" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;" value="${i}">
            <button onclick="contadormas(${c})">+</button>
            </li>`
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('lista_alumnos_conectados').innerHTML = text;
});

function contadormas (index) {
    document.getElementById(`${index}`).value++;
}

function contadormenos (index) {
    var cant = document.getElementById(`${index}`).value--;
}
```

```html
<a id="btnVerAlumnos">Lista de alumnos</a>
<ul id="lista_alumnos_conectados"></ul>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, por la rapidez de tu respuesta y tu aporte. Ahora veré como puedo mantener los datos en memoria porque eso está en un modal y cada vez que lo vuelvo a abrir, se reinicia.

Answer (score 0):

aquí tengo un buen ejemplo utilizando menos codigo y con una sola función

```js
function cantidad( id_input, operacion){
  var numero=$('#'+id_input).val();
  if(operacion=='1'){
    numero++;
  } else{
    numero--;
  }
  $('#'+id_input).val(numero);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="cantidad(3,0)">-</button>
<input id="3" type="text" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;" value="1">
<button onclick="cantidad(3,1)">+</button>

<button onclick="cantidad(5,0)">-</button>
<input id="5" type="text" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;" value="1">
<button onclick="cantidad(5,1)">+</button>
```

Comment: Vaya con solo una función, ¿por qué no? muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: si le sirve la soluciones deber marca la fecha hacia arriba